# how to extract integration order (d) from auto.arima

Tags: r

basically we can extract optimum AR order from auto.arima by

```
> auto.arima(ret.fin.chn,trace=TRUE,allowdrift=TRUE)

  ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean : -14242.19
  ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean : -14239.24
  ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : -14241.3
  ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : -14238.16
  ARIMA(1,0,2) with non-zero mean : -14237.65
  ARIMA(3,0,2) with non-zero mean : -14242.72
  ARIMA(3,0,1) with non-zero mean : -14239.52
  ARIMA(3,0,3) with non-zero mean : -14242.5
  ARIMA(2,0,1) with non-zero mean : -14237.15
  ARIMA(4,0,3) with non-zero mean : -14238.06
  ARIMA(3,0,2) with zero mean     : -14244.39
  ARIMA(2,0,2) with zero mean     : -14243.98
  ARIMA(4,0,2) with zero mean     : -14241.45
  ARIMA(3,0,1) with zero mean     : -14241.23
  ARIMA(3,0,3) with zero mean     : -14244.04
  ARIMA(2,0,1) with zero mean     : -14238.78
  ARIMA(4,0,3) with zero mean     : -14239.73


 Best model: ARIMA(3,0,2) with zero mean


 Series: ret.fin.chn 
 ARIMA(3,0,2) with zero mean     

 Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2     ar3      ma1     ma2
       0.5497  -0.4887  0.0461  -0.5691  0.4923
 s.e.  0.3525   0.1764  0.0232   0.3534  0.1878

 sigma^2 estimated as 0.0003277:  log likelihood=7127.67
 AIC=-14243.35   AICc=-14243.32   BIC=-14207.83
 Warning messages:
 1: In if (is.constant(x)) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
 2: In if (is.constant(x)) return(d) :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
 3: In if (is.constant(dx)) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

now store the result to object a

```
> a<-auto.arima(ts(ret.fin.chn),trace=TRUE,allowdrift=TRUE)
```

then

```
> a$arma[1]
```

while for optimum MA order by

```
> a$arma[2]
```

now look at this part ***Best model: ARIMA(3,0,2) with zero mean***
this is the ARIMA(p,d,q) order
i've known how to extract the AR(p) and MA(q) order but how to extract the Integration(d) order and note in mind that i've tried the `ndiffs` and sometimes it gives different result than the best model perhaps it's somewhere in `$arma[?]`???

Comment: The `auto.arima()` function uses `nsdiffs()` to determine `D` (the number of seasonal differences to use), and `ndiffs()` to determine `d` (the number of ordinary differences to use). The selection of the other model parameters `(p,q,P and Q)` are all determined by minimizing the AICc, as with non-seasonal ARIMA models.

Source : https://otexts.org/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html might

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, the order (d) is the next to last element; the seasonal order (D) is the last.  So-

- `a$arma[length(a$arma)-1]` is the order d
- `a$arma[length(a$arma)]` is the seasonal order

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Rob Hyndman, one of the authors of the `forecast` package, in [an answer to a similar question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/178635/212509), an easy way to extract the order vector `(p,d,q)` is to use the `forecast::arimaorder` function.

In your example, this would work as follows:

```
arimaorder(a)
```

The output is a named integer with the values of `p`, `d` and `q`:

```
p d q 
3 0 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see from the help file of `arima` under Value (`auto.arima` has the same Value as `arima`)

*arma

    A compact form of the specification, as a vector giving the number of AR, MA, seasonal AR and seasonal MA coefficients, plus the period and the number of non-seasonal and seasonal differences.*

So value `a$arma[6]` contains non-seasonal difference and `a$arma[7]` contains seasonal difference.

Comment: actually i was expecting somewhere between `$arma[5]` or `$arma[6]` since the help file states that `$arma[5]` to `$arma[7]` represent the period and the number of non-seasonal and seasonal differences in that order what i didn't know was which value are taken into `d`, i don't know i'll try look into it again

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry Metrics it seems that your solution isn't quite right

```
> auto.arima(fin.gre,trace=TRUE,allowdrift=TRUE)$arma

 ARIMA(2,2,2)                    : 26148.84
 ARIMA(0,2,0)                    : 27846.32
 ARIMA(1,2,0)                    : 27209.88
 ARIMA(0,2,1)                    : 26161.36
 ARIMA(1,2,2)                    : 26146.27
 ARIMA(1,2,1)                    : 26144.37
 ARIMA(1,2,1)                    : 26144.37
 ARIMA(2,2,1)                    : 26146.69

 Best model: ARIMA(1,2,1)                    

a<-auto.arima(fin.gre,trace=TRUE,allowdrift=TRUE)

a$arma
[1] 1 1 0 0 1 2 0
```

while doing `str(a)` yields

```
    > str(a)
List of 16
 $ coef     : Named num [1:2] 0.0715 -0.9969
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "ar1" "ma1"
 $ sigma2   : num 795
 $ var.coef : num [1:2, 1:2] 3.65e-04 -3.19e-06 -3.19e-06 3.39e-06
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "ar1" "ma1"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "ar1" "ma1"
 $ mask     : logi [1:2] TRUE TRUE
 $ loglik   : num -13078
 $ aic      : num 26162
 $ arma     : int [1:7] 1 1 0 0 1 2 0
 $ residuals: Time-Series [1:2750] from 1 to 2750: 0.39 -1.15 -3.64 -4.65 -11.57 ...
 $ call     : language auto.arima(x = structure(list(x = c(872.5, 880.78, 884.1, 884.1, 874.45, 855.3, 844.81,  837.14, 828.08, 830.74, 835.36, 839.25, 819.54, 802.27, 798.25, 793.01, 816.43, 831.87,  ...
 $ series   : chr "fin.gre"
 $ code     : int 0
 $ n.cond   : int 0
 $ model    :List of 10
  ..$ phi  : num 0.0715
  ..$ theta: num -0.997
  ..$ Delta: num [1:2] 2 -1
  ..$ Z    : num [1:4] 1 0 2 -1
  ..$ a    : num [1:4] 1.01 -1.72 62.87 62.78
  ..$ P    : num [1:4, 1:4] -2.22e-16 2.21e-16 1.74e-16 4.62e-17 2.21e-16 ...
  ..$ T    : num [1:4, 1:4] 0.0715 0 1 0 1 ...
  ..$ V    : num [1:4, 1:4] 1 -0.997 0 0 -0.997 ...
  ..$ h    : num 0
  ..$ Pn   : num [1:4, 1:4] 1.00 -9.97e-01 9.51e-17 1.71e-16 -9.97e-01 ...
 $ bic      : num 26180
 $ aicc     : num 26162
 $ x        :An ‘xts’ object on 2003-01-01/2013-07-16 containing:
  Data: num [1:2750, 1] 872 881 884 884 874 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "Arima"
```

as you can see the `$model[3]` contain two number from `$arma[5]` and `$arma[6]`it seems that `$arma[5]` represent integration order `d`, but im not really sure about it